# How to convert Mupad symbol 'I' {sqrt(-1)} to 'i' in matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, complex-numbers

I am trying to evaluate this integral in matlab
[image]

matlab is treating 'ans' as a symbol because of 'I'. How to convert this 'I' into 'i' so that ans becomes a complex number.

much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The symbolic math toolbox has an overloaded `double` function that can be used to convert from `sym` to `double` representation (if the expression is a symbolic constant or is a constant expression).

For example:

```
ans_sym = vpa(1+1*i);
ans_double = double(ans_sym);
```

Look here for more information: http://www.mathworks.se/help/toolbox/symbolic/double.html.