# How to Preallocate memory in Large Symbolic Matrix manipulation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

**How to Preallocate memory in Large Symbolic Matrix manipulation in MATLAB.**

For eg: In code given below size of variable "Toc" and "Tnw" increase in each iteration. I have tried preallocation by `Toc = zeros(0,50)`   but there is error "**error occurred converting from sym to double**". So what is symbolic version of syntax for Preallocation?

```
syms c z
Tnw = 1;
for i = 1:9
    Toc(c, z) = [(1-c)*z c-c*z ; -c+c*z (1+c)*z];
    f = collect(Toc(c,z));
    Tnw = Tnw*f;
end
```

So what is best practice used for Preallocation in  large symbolic manipulation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this gets you started: [Creating Object Arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html)

Comment: Or have a look at [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201050/matlab-convert-output-from-symbolic-math-to-float/16201051#16201051)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `zeros(0,50)` is not going to allocate anything. It't an empty vector. It's also a vector of type double, which is why you're getting the error when you try to store symbolic values in it. I'm not sure about "best practice", but this is how I allocate symbolic arrays.

```
Toc = sym(zeros(1,50));
```

A double array is allocated and then recast as symbolic. *UPDATE*: In newer versions of Matlab you can use `zeros(1,50,'sym')` or `zeros(1,50,'like',Y)`, where `Y` is a symbolic variable of any size.

However, in your example the dimensions of the `Tnw` and `Toc` arrays do not grow each iteration as you state. What grows is length of the strings in each element of `Tnw`. I think that this may be what you're really asking about and I don't think that this is something that you can preallocate. You have to leave it up to the symbolic engine.

Lastly, it appears that you're needlessly using a symbolic function (`symfun`) instead of a generic symbolic array for `Toc`. These two lines would be the same:

```
Toc = [(1-c)*z c-c*z ; -c+c*z (1+c)*z];
f = collect(Toc);
```