# How can I bring matlab to evaluate output after using substitution?

Tags: matlab, substitution

I have a problem in matlab using the substitution of symbols with values. Everything works just fine - the only problem is that my output after substitution looks for example like this:

- exp(-1) - 1/2

Obviously, I would prefer matlab to compute one value in evaluating the exponential function. If I just enter the term, matlab gives the desired result -0.8679. Is there a possibility that matlab calculates the value by itself?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Are you using the Symbolic Toolbox / Mupad?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab: Convert output from symbolic math to float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201050/matlab-convert-output-from-symbolic-math-to-float)