# why I cannot get just a number

Tags: matlab

I did following:

```
clc
clear all
I0=1.2e12;
FWHM=10e-12;
c=FWHM./2.35482;
t=0:1e-12:50e-12;
syms t
int(I0.*exp(-1.*(t-5e-12).^2./(2.*c.^2)),t,0,40e-12)
```

but it does not give me a simple number (just a number)

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `double(int(I0.*exp(-1.*(t-5e-12).^2./(2.*c.^2)),t,0,40e-12))` - that turns your expression into a number. Have a look at this question: [Convert output from symbolic math sym to float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201050/convert-output-from-symbolic-math-sym-to-float)

Comment: @Schorsch Indeed `double` seems the right command, I have updated my answer. Technically this question asks why, rather than how, but the linked question is definitely related.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I guess the "why" is answered by: Because the result of a symbolic equation is a symbolic number - which follows what you say in the first sentence of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why matlab does not automatically give you a number is that precision could be lost.

Suppose you have a symbolic variable with value `1/3`. That has infinite accuracy at this point. Yet if you evaluate it, you would lose this precision, so that is why it is not evaluated directly.

If you want to evaluate it, you could do that of course. Try `doc double`,`doc vpa`, `doc eval` or `doc subs`. I think the first one is what you need.